# replace elements in a list with another

Tags: java, list

How do I replace elements in a `list` with another?

For example I want all `two` to become `one`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use:

```
Collections.replaceAll(list, "two", "one");
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll(java.util.List,%20T,%20T)):

> Replaces all occurrences of one specified value in a list with another. More formally, replaces with `newVal` each element `e` in list such that `(oldVal==null ? e==null : oldVal.equals(e))`. (This method has no effect on the size of the list.)

The method also return a `boolean` to indicate whether or not any replacement was actually made.

[`java.util.Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) has many more `static` utility methods that you can use on `List` (e.g. `sort`, `binarySearch`, `shuffle`, etc).

---

#### Snippet

The following shows how `Collections.replaceAll` works; it also shows that you can replace to/from `null` as well:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "one", "two", "three", null, "two", null, "five"
    );
    System.out.println(list);
    // [one, two, three, null, two, null, five]

    Collections.replaceAll(list, "two", "one");
    System.out.println(list);
    // [one, one, three, null, one, null, five]

    Collections.replaceAll(list, "five", null);
    System.out.println(list);
    // [one, one, three, null, one, null, null]

    Collections.replaceAll(list, null, "none");
    System.out.println(list);
    // [one, one, three, none, one, none, none]
```