# ArrayList replaceAll() not working

Tags: java, arraylist, replaceall

I don't know what's the problem in my code.Whatever I try to replace, not wroking.
I have a `private static ArrayList<String> lista`.

I fill this. Then later in another method, whatever I try, I can't replace anything, like this:

```
public static void replacing() {
    Collections.replaceAll(lista, "a", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Then I print this in the method and lista is the same, nothing changed. What should I check after?

```
public class MyProgram {
    private static ArrayList < String > lista;
    public static void fileReading() {
        lista = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            inp = new LineNumberReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileNev), "ISO8859-1")));
            String sor;
            while ((sor = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                lista.add(sor);
                lista.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            inp.close();
        } catch...
    }
    public static void searching() {
        Collections.replaceAll(lista, "a", "b");
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider to edit your question and add your `lista` contents since your snippet looks correct

Comment: what does  lista contain and how did you create it?

Comment: Please be specific. What exactly do you put into the list? Post the complete code that creates a list, adds into it, and tries to call your method.

Comment: does your lista contains an element/String "a"????

Comment: Details matter on this, so I agree with the requests for more data. For example, the string "a" is not equal to the character 'a'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace elements in a list with another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317691/replace-elements-in-a-list-with-another)

Comment: What is the return value of the `replaceAll()` call?

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to replace any character 'a' in any of the elements in your ArrayList with the string "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" ??

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan its a list of Strings so if you use that method, you replace Strings, not characters. If you wanted to replace characters you would have to get the String first, which is not the case here.

Comment: @bluekant same comment as above.

Comment: what is the content of the file you are reading?

Answer (score 11):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a","b"});      
System.out.println(list);
Collections.replaceAll(list, "a", "!!!!!");
System.out.println(list);
```

gives

```
[a, b]
[!!!!!, b]
```

The above code sample shows that `Collections.replaceAll` indeed works.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example explaining Collections.replaceAll

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> sLst = new ArrayList<String>();
        sLst.add("A");
        sLst.add("B");
        sLst.add("C");
        sLst.add("A");
        // This will replace all "A" with "Z"
        Collections.replaceAll(sLst, "A", "Z");
        System.out.println(sLst);// [Z, B, C, Z]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a","ba",new String("a")});      
Collections.replaceAll(list, "a", "!!!!!");
System.out.println(list);
```

output would be

`!!!!! ba !!!!!`

it would not replace 'a' in "ba"

Comment: Thank you all.
I can only give the relevant code in 2 answers:

public class MyProgram {
    private static ArrayList<String> lista;

 public static void fileReading() {

 lista = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    inp = new LineNumberReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileNev), "ISO8859-1")));

     String sor;
     while ((sor = inp.readLine()) != null) {
          lista.add(sor);
          lista.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

Comment: inp.close();
    } catch...
    }

public static void searching() {

         Collections.replaceAll(lista, "a", "b");
         System.out.println(lista.toString());
}
}

I tried this, but it only prints the original lista
It contains several 'a' and tried with others, but it replaced nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure is this the right method I'm looking for.
I need the replace old string like: abc(... or abc ( , where I'd like to replace "abc" to a new string like "xyz". 
"abc" is a method name, so I must search for '(' too, and replace just the name, and leave what's after
Would replaceAll() work fine for this?